# dynamic redirects with two submit button in django generic update view

Tags: django

Trying to redirect to two views in get success url method, but didn't work. My html button is as follows.

```
<input type="submit" name="addMore" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Save and Add More">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Save and Exit">
```

Tried in my generic update views, as follows, but throws TypeError at /add_experience/
quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

```
class ExperienceCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Experience
    form_class = ExperienceCreateForm
    template_name = 'employees/experience_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        if 'addMore' in self.request.POST:
            return redirect('add_experience')
        return redirect("emp_profile_list")
```

Comment: Can you post the full view code?

Comment: updated with full view